# Isn't added admob sdk to wp8.1 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone, admob

I get sdk from https://developers.google.com/admob/wp/download?hl=ru and tried add his to my Windows phone 8.1 SilverLight project. But VS say me "incompatible assembly".
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the wp8 admob control in wp8.1 you can serve admob ads in the ad rotator control.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdRotator/